# Why can't I break the Java loop

Tags: java, multithreading

I cannot reach the last line in my code even though I used `synchronized`.
However, if I add something between the loop, it worked well.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int test_time = 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
        //warm up
    }
    long t = 0;
    t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    byte[] b = new byte[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < test_time; i++) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String i = getUserInf(); //get something from web
                synchronized (b) {
                    ++times;
                    System.out.println(times);
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }

    while (times != test_time){
        // System.out.println(String.format("times=%s,test_time=%s", times,test_time));     
        // if i added this line, it worked well
    }
    System.out.println("time:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - t));
}
```

Comment: Where is `times` declared? Is it volatile?

Comment: Your threads may be updating `times` in a non-thread-safe way. Not sure why you are locking on an empty byte array. Perhaps you should explain what you want to achieve and we can help you write this in a better way.

Comment: thx,@ Eran ,i declared times as a class variable.

Comment: @Duncan ,I just wanna know how long it it takes while getting some thing from web service using the method getUserInf().

Comment: @Duncan I tried synchronized (this) instead, but not worked.

Comment: @user3714382 if you wants to know how long getUserInf() takes, the easiest way is to print time around the method call. Use System.nanoTime() to calculate the difference for example.

Comment: You used `synchronized`, but you only used it in the new thread.  There is no synchronization between the new thread and the main thread.  One way to achieve that would be to do what @grape_mao said, declare `times` to be `volatile`  Another way would be to use a `synchronized` block in the main thread each time you access `times`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your variable `times` as `volatile int`. Because when it's read in the while loop from the main thread, it is not guarded by `b`. The call to `System.out.println` is synchronized, so the value of `times` gets updated and becomes visible.